# Unable to Implement Map Clustering in React Native Using Various Packages

Tags: react-native-maps, react-native-mapbox-gl, react-native-map-clustering

I'm trying to implement map clustering in my React Native project, but I'm encountering difficulties with various packages I've tried. I attempted to use react-native-clusterer, react-native-maps-clustering, and react-native-maps-super-cluster, but none of them seem to work.

The error I'm consistently encountering is:
[Error: undefined Unable to resolve module react-native-map-clustering from E:\path\to\my\project\file.js: react-native-map-clustering could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules

This error occurs when I try to import the clustering package in my code like:
import MapView from "react-native-map-clustering";

I have verified that the packages are installed correctly using npm, and I've followed the installation instructions provided by each package's documentation. However, I'm still unable to resolve this error.

Has anyone successfully implemented map clustering in a React Native project using one of these packages? If so, could you provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help!